# How to keep scrollbar from resetting position on binding update?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is there a way to keep a scrollbar in its current position so it doesnt reset everytime the binding to the text property of the textbox is updated in accordance with mvvm?

Comment: You could certainly do it manually by storing and setting the position of the textbox's `ScrollViewer` on rebind. Not sure if there is any neater solution or not.